# Microsoft Word document should be filllable but isn't

Tags: microsoft-word

I need to write up a 20-page description of something. I was sent a Microsoft Word document dated 2008 to use as a template. The document I was sent has a large number of checkboxes. They appear to be form fields. It would make my life much easier if I could just click and check the boxes as appropriate instead of trying to somehow copy the look of the checkboxes... but the form isn't actually fillable. There is text from a previous project in the document already and it appears to have been filled out using the form fields, such as city names that were selected from drop-down lists and boxes that have been checked. But the only ways for me to make edits are to either a) delete the entire field and just type it in, or b) click the field and change the default settings.

I've never seen a fillable form like this and it's driving me crazy. What could have led it it, and is there any way I can get it into a re-fillable state?

Comment: You need to ask the person who sent you the form for instructions, or to correct the file. If a form was created and the document protected, you cannot modify it.

Comment: Is the document “protected for forms” ?

Comment: Check if  there is the feature [Restrict Editing](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/create-forms-that-users-complete-or-print-in-word-040c5cc1-e309-445b-94ac-542f732c8c8b) enabled for the form fields.

Comment: So the way I ended up filling this out: turn on restrict editing to check the boxes, turn it off to write in text, turn it back on to check the boxes, turn it off to write in text...